# Control emission shader's falloff using an RGB curve

Tags: rendering, materials, lighting

I have an image light whom I wish to **rapidly decay**. So I'm trying to mess with it using the curves like on the screenshot I posted. I'm trying with the curve here but to no avail. Could someone guide me towards my goal; to have a light with rapid decay rate?

[image]

Comment: Could you show some example of what you want to achieve?

Comment: I tried googling "rapid light falloff" but wasn't helping. 
I don't need the exact values , I can play that meself, but currently the color ramp doesn't do anything and the RGB curve seems to do everything just randomly. I only need the _how to_ modify light falloff besides the falloff node.

Comment: Sorry I can't help here as I don't understand properly what should final effect looks like.

Comment: Basically very strong lighting when close to the light source and almost pitch black when just a step further.

Comment: why not use the 'Ray Length' from the Light Path node?

Comment: I don't know how to make such falloff but it's pretty simple with another object which will behave as light boundaries.

Comment: Both of those are good ideas, I go check them out right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Overview:

[image: Final]

I've used default **Cylinder** with two materials.

First assigned to the top face it's an **Emission** shader.

Second assigned to the rest of the **Cylinder** - **Holdout** to prevent light from 'spreading', **Transparent** to be invisible and those mixed by **Light Path > Is Camera Ray** to show us only **Transparency**.

Comment: Thanks, was looking for something quire similar to this.